# Python CSV Reader fmtparams

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 different lines of code:

```
f = open("file.csv", "rt")
```

and:

```
f = open("file.csv", "rb")
```

I've been trying to search online for what this means, but all I could find was other examples. I want to know is what `rt` and `rb` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered looking at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open)?

Comment: D'oh! When I tried Googling it, I only found this link, which wasn't what I wanted:

http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/csv.html

On the link you gave me, it doesn't define 't'. Do you know?

Thanks.

Comment: `t` isn't used much because it's the default: text mode, in which Python will convert line endings found in files to `\n` when read and back to the platform-specific line-endings when written, as opposed to `b` (binary) mode, which reads everything as-is.

Comment: With regards to csv in Python.  In Python 2 you need to open csv files in binary mode, in Python 3 you open them in text mode.

Comment: it doesn't appear that the linked documentation contains any references to fmtparams as of 2017